Visual Studio 2022 React with Typescript ASP.NET MSB3073 npm install exited with code 1
I'm trying to learn how to develop a full-stack app but while trying to use the React with Typescript and ASP.NET template I cant get to run it.
Heres the error code that I keep getting
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  MSB3073 The command "npm install" exited with code 1.   loginapp1.client    C:\Users\gfarias.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\1.0.1184077\Sdk\Sdk.targets Line:264
typ0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node.exe C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@10.5.2
2 info using node@v20.13.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\gfarias\Documents\LoginApp1\loginapp1.client\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\gfarias\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 1ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm ls
22 verbose argv "ls" "--json" "--long"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 0ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\gfarias\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-02T19_23_15_856Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\gfarias\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-02T19_23_15_856Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 4ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 35ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 timing command:ls Completed in 400ms
35 verbose stack Error: missing: @eslint/js@^9.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: @types/node@^20.17.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: @types/react-dom@^18.3.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: @types/react@^18.3.3, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: @vitejs/plugin-react@^4.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^5.1.0-rc.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: eslint-plugin-react-refresh@^0.4.9, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: eslint@^9.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: globals@^15.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: react-dom@^18.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: react@^18.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: typescript-eslint@^8.0.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: typescript@^5.5.3, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack missing: vite@^5.4.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
35 verbose stack     at LS.exec (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\ls.js:203:9)
35 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js:61:5)
36 verbose cwd C:\Users\gfarias\Documents\LoginApp1\loginapp1.client
37 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
38 verbose node v20.13.1
39 verbose npm  v10.5.2
40 error code ELSPROBLEMS
41 error missing: @eslint/js@^9.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: @types/node@^20.17.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: @types/react-dom@^18.3.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: @types/react@^18.3.3, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: @vitejs/plugin-react@^4.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^5.1.0-rc.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: eslint-plugin-react-refresh@^0.4.9, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: eslint@^9.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: globals@^15.9.0, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: react-dom@^18.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: react@^18.3.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: typescript-eslint@^8.0.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: typescript@^5.5.3, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
41 error missing: vite@^5.4.1, required by loginapp1.client@0.0.0
42 verbose exit 1
43 timing npm Completed in 484ms
44 verbose code 1
45 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\gfarias\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-09-02T19_23_15_856Z-debug-0.log
e here

Tried to run the app, and it exited with a code error from npm install.
Has anyone encountered this error?
I've tried different stuff like changing the directory of the project or running VS2022 as administrator but nothing seems to work.

This is definitely not the way to go if you're new to full stack. Combining TS with ASP.Net is really weird. I strongly recommend finding (more than one) tutorials for full stack that start small and work their way up. Visual Studio will 100% guaranteed not be involved. Although "VS Code" probably is (which has nothing to do with visual studio).

Isn't the back-end made in VS 2022 ? At least most tutorials seem to do it there.

Only if you need ASP.Net, which in 2024 makes... very little sense. If you don't have a very specific reason to use ASP.Net, and you're just trying to learning how do full stack, don't use an IIS-and-Windows-specific backend. Node itself is already your backend, and it's platform-agnostic, the "standard" server component for it is express, and there are plenty of popular full stack solutions that you can jump in to and know that others will be able to help when you get stuck, like Vite, Nextjs, Angular, etc.

I had seen those full stack solutions but I'm currently an intern in a company and my tasked project is to make a ReactJS template since the one they have is outdated. They need the back-end to be in NET so I don't have much of a choice, hope I can talk to my supervisor and try figure something out. Thanks for the advice!

Then why did you not mention that in your post? Hit [edit] and put that information into your post (not as "edit: I have to ..." but just update the text to read like a normal, but now more complete, post)
